# SQLite for Android - Trying to query String values from different rows

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the next table - let's call it - TABLE_ITEMS

```
  id |  tilte    |  body
________________________
  0     apple       red
  1     orange      orange
  2     grapes      green
  3     apple       green
  4     apple       red
```

Now I'm try to use two different queries -

In the first one i want to get all the rows that have green under "body" - so to do this I've used the next code :

```
public Cursor queryByBody(String color){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpen.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_ITMES, null,
            Constants.ITEM_BODY + "='" + color+ "'", null, null, null, null);

    int x =c.getCount(); 
    Log.d("GOT INTO DB", "COUNT IS "+ x);
    return c;

}
```

As you can see there's the variable x - when i look at the logcat it says 0.

Another thing that I'm trying to do is to get rows by looking at the "title" and "body"

In order to do that I used the next code:

```
public Cursor queryByCatAndBodyType(String title, String body){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpen.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_ITMES, null,
        Constants.ITEM_TITLE + "='" + title + "' AND " + Constants.ITEM_BODY + "='"+ body +"'", null, null, null, null);

    int x =c.getCount(); 
    Log.d("GOT INTO DB", "COUNT IS "+ x);
    return c;

}
```

But yet again the count is 0 and i don't get any results.

On the other hand I tried the next code -

```
    public Cursor queryById(int id){

      SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpen.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_ITMES, null,
            Constants.ITEM_ID + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
    int x =c.getCount(); 
    Log.d("GOT INTO DB", " count "+x );
    return c;
}
```

And this time I've got a result.

So what am I doing wrong with the first two quires?
Am i missing something?

Thanks for any kind of  help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the way the Android SQLite library handles constructed this way queries.
Try to change your first call to query() like this, it will work (if there are no other problems):

```
Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_ITMES, null,
            Constants.ITEM_BODY + "=?", new String[]{color}, null, null, null);
```

**Edit**
If you still have problems - try to move **step by step**:

1) log the value of target column when you get result, like this, may be it will answer your question:

```
public Cursor queryById(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpen.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_ITMES, null,
            Constants.ITEM_ID + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
    int x =c.getCount(); 
/*edited here*/    c.moveToFirst();
/*and here*/    Log.d("GOT INTO DB", " count "+x +", body "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( Constants.ITEM_BODY)));
    return c;
}
```

2) Try to query for predefined value:

```
Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_ITMES, null,
            Constants.ITEM_BODY + "=?", new String[]{"green"}, null, null, null);
```

3) Try to use 'like' operator:

```
Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_ITMES, null,
            Constants.ITEM_BODY + " like ?", new String[]{"%green%"}, null, null, null);
```

4) Try to use old straightforward query like this:

```
String query = "select * from " + Constants.TABLE_ITMES + " where " + Constants.ITEM_BODY + "=?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{color});
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work - don't know why. like I said i tired to check by id and I am getting a result -so it means there are values in the table

Comment: it's strange, I've done a lot of similar queries... Try to debug issue using the steps I've added in edit